# Match a string between multiple whitespaces

Tags: regex, string, perl

Hello can anyone help me with a regex to match a string between multiple whitespaces

My string may look like this :

```
This is just          Nicolas-764 sdh            and   his sister
```

I want to match `Nicolas-764 sdh`

So far I wrote this but it matches all the string after the first whitespaces

```
if ($string =~ m/(just) {5,}(.*) {5,}/) {
          print "$1\n";
          print "$2\n";
}
```

I want to create a hash that will have as key `just` and as value `Nicolas-764 sdh`. 
I don't want to just match a string between multiple spaces. I need to use `just` too

Comment: `and` is also between multiple spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be,

```
if ($string =~ m/^.*?just {5,}(\S+)\s+(\S+) {5,}.*$/) {
          print "$1\n";
          print "$2\n";
}
```

First group contains `Nicolas-764` and the second group contains `sdh`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sQ0kW4/5)

Or

You could try the below regex also,

```
^.*?just {5,}(\S+(?:\s\S+)*?) {5,}.*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserst that we are at the start of the line.
- `.*?just` This would match upto the first `just` string. `?` after `*` does a non-greedy match.
- `{5,}` Matches 5 or more spaces.
- `()` Capturing groups.
- `\S+` One or more non-space characters.
- `(?:)` Non-capturing groups. It won't capture anything. Just matching would be done.
- `(?:\s\S+)*?` Matches a space followed by one or more non-space characters. And the whole would occur zero or more times.
- `{5,}` Matches 5 or more spaces.
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end of the line.

Comment: I have updated the question. I want to be clear that in the second group I can have multiple words, which will be separated by a whitespace. I know when the group is over, when I find more than one whitespace.

Comment: Well that works but isn't there a way to match it all at once? Why did you use 2 groups?

Comment: Ok, I will accept this answer as soon as they let me, about 5 min. Until then can you explain a little what happends in that regex. I don't understand the meaning of `:` and why did you use that `$` at the end

Answer (score 1):

You're suffering from greedy matching `.*`.

You simply need to change to non-greedy matching using `.*?`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'This is just          Nicolas-764 sdh            and   his sister';

if ($string =~ m/just\s{5,}(.*?)\s{5,}/) {
     print "$1\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
Nicolas-764 sdh
```